# Ender 5 BlTouch Install

Tags: bltouch, creality-ender-5, bigtreetech

I just installed a BLTouch on my Ender 5 but I'm having trouble installing/editing the firmware. After watching a few YouTube videos, I figured going to the GitHub BTT Marlin repository (because I have a Bigtreetech E3 mini V2 board in it) would be easiest. After leveling the bed without issues, I attempted a print but it started way too high (20-30 mm above the bed). I know there is some type of offset I need to change but I don't know where it would be. My first thought was editing some of the configuration files in VS-Code before installing it on the printer but I downloaded the pre-compiled firmware.bin on GitHub that was already set up for the Ender-5 with a BTT E3 mini V2 board and a BLTouch. Is there anything I can do on the printer or in OctoPrint or should I start from scratch and edit the original Marlin files?

Answer (score 1):

After some research, the BlTouch can be wired to the mainboard two different ways; the 2 pin wires (that were black and white in the kit I bought) are able to plug into the probe spot with the 3 pin wires or they can replace the z-end-stop. I ended up replacing the z-end-stop wires with the 2 pin wires and downloaded pre-compiled firmware from GitHub.